# I want to run a javascript code on a site after it loads on computer

Tags: javascript, load

I want to run a javascript code on a site after it loads on computer.
For example when  I  open the google.com , after it loads , change it's background color by
js .
Is it possible ? how can i do it?

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: You can do that with userscripts, or by making browser extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TamperMonkey for Chrome or GreaseMonkey for Firefox.

Here's a sample TamperMonkey script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Change Google Background
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// ==/UserScript==

$('body').css('background', 'red');
```

Note that these changes are only local to the machine(s) that have the script installed.  You obviously can't change Google's background color for everyone!  ;-)